# How to implement parameterized arithmetic

Tags: java, generics, bigdecimal, primitive

I am designing a library that provides a huge collection of classes that perform heavy operations with numbers. I wouldn't like to limit users of the library to a single number type such as `int`, `double`, or `BigDecimal` - and so it would be nice if I could use generics to allow the user to choose their own number type. I am okay with the overhead posed by using primitive wrapper classes as opposed to primitives themselves, as would be necessary in order to use generics, but my problem lies in performing arithmetic.

If I create a hypothetical class `MathematicalObject<N extends Number>`, then the user can use any type for storing numbers that extends Number - `Integer`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`, et cetera. However the `Number` class does not provide any interface for arithmetic - I can't add two `Number`s without converting them to a `double` or something alike - which could compromise the accuracy of the number (if a `BigDecimal` was being used, for example).

So, what is the most performant way I can implement a parameterized use of numbers that allows me to perform arithmetic?

Comment: Since you don't have a specific coding question, this post may be more appropriate for the [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CubeJockey I think the question is specific enough for this site - I am asking how to perform arithmetic between two `Number`s, or an effective alternative.

Comment: No worries, if it's on-topic, then the post will stay. Just offering an alternative

Comment: @CubeJockey when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat you're right,  I was implying a deletion & repost sort of scenario. I will make myself more clear next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a factory to create a MathematicalObject. the constructor of MathematicalObject could accept a strategy class specifically for performing mathematical operations for that parameterised type, and the factory just chooses the right one based on what the parameterised type is.

```
public class MathemeaticalObject<N extends Number> {
    private final NumberOperations<N> ops;
    public MatchematicalObject(NumberOperations<N> ops) {
        this.ops = ops;
    }

    public N myComplexOperation(N other) {
        return ops.add(this, other);
    }
}

public class MathematicalObjectFactory {
    MathematicalObject<Integer> integerObject() {
        return new MathematicalObject(new IntegerOperations());
    }
    ....
}

public interface NumberOperations<N extends Number> {
    N add(N other);
}

public class IntegerOperations implements NumberOperations<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer add(Integer first, Integer second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

The downside would be that you're limited to what values of N are supported. But I think there might not be a way around that. It could also make for some messy code, given that the primitive mathematical operations aren't available directly.

Comment: Very intuitive solution - although you forgot to add the type parameters to `NumberOperations ops` in the constructor of `MathematicalObject` ;)

Comment: `MathemeaticalObject`: the perfect mix of math and meat

Comment: Yeah, "Warning! May not compile" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own Interface for aritmethic operations.
For using BigInteger or similiar classes, you could just subclass the class and make the subclass implement your interface.
For primitive types you would have to write your own Wrapper class :(

This is the design pattern Adapter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern